# How to locate the element in AngularJS application?

Tags: python, angularjs

I am automating the application with Selenium `webdriver` (python). Application is built in AngularJS and have encountered a problem in location the element as below:

```
<a title="Login/Sign Up" href="" id="login_box_button" ng-touchstart="loginsignup()" ng-hide="$storage.loggedInUser">Login/Sign Up</a>
```

Please help me locate this. I have tried `Xpath`, CSS but returned empty handed.

Tried using various `Xpaths` and CSS selectors.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Login/Sign Up' or @ng-touchstart='loginsignup()']").click()
```

Its not working. Getting error as :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@title='Login/Sign Up' or @ng-touchstart='loginsignup()']"}
```

(Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Your link text')]")
```

with this code you can find text on the page, without having to set up complex xpath